# Как внедрить JS на страницу View .cshtml в проекте C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

В отладчике Google chrome не отображается JS код на странице .cshtml и ощущение, что сервис его там вообще не определяет.
Прописываю следующем образом, но наверное что-то делаю не верно:

```
    @model CollectVoters.Models.Friend

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="IdFriend" />
              
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label asp-for="DateRegistrationSite" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="DateRegistrationSite" class="form-control" id="dateRegist" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="DateRegistrationSite" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label asp-for="VotingDate" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="VotingDate" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="VotingDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <input value="Текущая дата регистрации" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="stateDate('dateRegist')" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6" style="display:none">
                <label asp-for="UserId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="UserId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.UserId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <input type="submit" value="Сохранить" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block"><i class="fa fa-table"></i>Вернуться к списку</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
    function stateDate(idObject) {
        var today = new Date();
        //var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
        //var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
        //var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
        //today = dd + '-' + mm + '-' + yyyy;
        document.getElementById(idObject).innerHTML = today;
    }
</script>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}

    @{
        if (TempData["msg"] != null)
        {
            <script>
            alert('@TempData["msg"]')
            </script>
        }
    }
}
```

Вот что показывает отладчик:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И ни какой реакции на нажатие кнопки

```
<div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                <input value="Текущая дата регистрации" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="stateDate('dateRegist')" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Как-будто этого скрипта и нет.

Я подозреваю, что это связано с особенностями этого представление, но не пойму какими.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script>
       alert('foo');
    </script>
}
```

Частичное представление:

```
@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

Аналогичный вопрос на en so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37728814/5752652

Офдок: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Спасибо! Пробовал до этого помещал в эту секцию только функцию без <script>